# Why does Squid3 web proxy server block javascript files?

Tags: javascript, proxy, acl, ubuntu-14.04, squid

Hi and thank you for reading my question.

I have a fresh installation of squid3 proxy server (version 3.3.8) on ubuntu server 14.04 LTS.

I am using squid just to filter some web sites so I am not using its caching capability.

The problem is squid blocks js files (I can see them in chrome console blocked with Error message 503 Service Unreahable) so web pages are not loaded correctly.

I am redirecting https and http traffic to squid tcp port 3128. But I am not filtering any web site.

Is there anything I missed while configuring squid?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If I dont redirect https traffic to squid port how can I filter sites like facebook or twitter ? This is how I wanted it to work: Acess to internet connection must be only via proxy. So browser should be configured to point at squid proxy server. Suppose that I dont redirect https port 443 to squid port 3128 and user does not configure its browser so he can easily open all https sites and proxy becomes useless. If you say it is a bad idea to redirect https traffic so any idea how can I block some https sites without port redirection. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`I am redirecting https and http traffic to squid tcp port 3128. But I am not filtering any web site.` using iptables? or set in the browser? 
if yout use iptables to redirect 443 to 3128 is not good!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to read HTTPS using Squid.

First because Squid/you will have to generate a new self-signed certificate per website you access.

Secondly major websites are using Key pinning which makes impossible to change the certificate even you have your own CA deployed.

Check the HPKP rfc.

Comment: HPKP may be easily filtered from headers. Squid has SslBump mode that generates certificated on the fly. All you need is to import its certificate on client hosts.